# FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 919

Tags: android

Am try to create a camera app. In this app take pictures and apply several filters to the pictures taken. Filters are implemented by OpenGL. This app is **working only in Nexus5** in other device it will be **force close** with **FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread**.  Thanks!

Logcat error is given below

```
10-28 18:28:55.215    6217-6449/com.camera_with_filter.camera_filter E/ShaderHelper﹕ Error compiling shader: Compile failed.
ERROR: 0:1: 'vec2' : No precision defined for this type
ERROR: 1 compilation errors. No code generated.10-28 18:28:55.253    6217-6449/com.camera_with_filter.camera_filter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 660
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating shader.
        at com.camera_with_filter.camera_filter.ShaderHelper.compileShader(ShaderHelper.java:44)
        at com.camera_with_filter.camera_filter.MyGLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(MyGLRenderer.java:156)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1266)
```

**1.SaderHelper.java**

public class ShaderHelper
{
    private static final String TAG = "ShaderHelper";

```
/** 
 * Helper function to compile a shader.
 * 
 * @param shaderType The shader type.
 * @param shaderSource The shader source code.
 * @return An OpenGL handle to the shader.
 */
public static int compileShader(final int shaderType, final String shaderSource) 
{
    int shaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);

    if (shaderHandle != 0) 
    {
        // Pass in the shader source.
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shaderHandle, shaderSource);

        // Compile the shader.
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

        // Get the compilation status.
        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

        // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
        if (compileStatus[0] == 0) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error compiling shader: " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shaderHandle);
            shaderHandle = 0;
        }
    }

    if (shaderHandle == 0)
    {           
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader.");
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}

/**
 * Helper function to compile and link a program.
 * 
 * @param vertexShaderHandle An OpenGL handle to an already-compiled vertex shader.
 * @param fragmentShaderHandle An OpenGL handle to an already-compiled fragment shader.
 * @param attributes Attributes that need to be bound to the program.
 * @return An OpenGL handle to the program.
 */
public static int createAndLinkProgram(final int vertexShaderHandle, final int fragmentShaderHandle, final String[] attributes) 
{
    int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    if (programHandle != 0) 
    {
        // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);           

        // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

        // Bind attributes
        if (attributes != null)
        {
            final int size = attributes.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, i, attributes[i]);
            }                       
        }

        // Link the two shaders together into a program.
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

        // Get the link status.
        final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

        // If the link failed, delete the program.
        if (linkStatus[0] == 0) 
        {               
            Log.e(TAG, "Error compiling program: " + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
            programHandle = 0;
        }
    }

    if (programHandle == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
    }

    return programHandle;
}
```

}

**2.MyGLRender**

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements Renderer {
private final Context mActivityContext;
private String mFilepath;

private final FloatBuffer mTexcoordPositions;
private final FloatBuffer mVerticesPositions;

private int mImageUniformHandle;
private int mStepUniformHandle;

private int mProgramHandle;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mTexcoordHandle;


private int mEmbossProgram;
private int mBlurProgram;
private int mEdgeProgram;
private int mGrayScaleProgram;
private int mNegProgram;
private int mToonshadingProgram;
private int mNormalProgram;
private int height = 1600;
private int width = 900;

private int mProgramID = 1;

private int mTextureDataHandle;
private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;

private final int mPositionDataSize = 2;
private final int mTexcoordDataSize = 2;

private boolean mScreenshot;
private final float[] vertices = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f
};
private final float[] texcoords = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
};

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "Position");
    mTexcoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "Texcoords");
    mStepUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_step");
    mImageUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_image");


    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
    if (mImageUniformHandle != -1)
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mImageUniformHandle, 0);
    if (mStepUniformHandle != -1)
        GLES20.glUniform2f(mStepUniformHandle, 1.0f / (float) width, 1.0f / (float) height);
    Draw();
    if (mScreenshot == true)
        Log.d("mScreenshot", "true");
    if (mScreenshot) {
        Log.d("screenshot", "start");
        int screenshotSize = width * height;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
        int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];
        bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
        bb = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize - width, -width, 0, 0, width, height);
        pixelsBuffer = null;

        short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
        ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);

        //Making created bitmap (from OpenGL points) compatible with Android bitmap
        for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {
            short v = sBuffer[i];
            sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v & 0x1f) << 11) | (v & 0x7e0) | ((v & 0xf800) >> 11));
        }
        sb.rewind();
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);
        try {
            StringBuffer sbFilepath = new StringBuffer(mFilepath);
            String sProgType = getProgramType();
            int insertIdx = sbFilepath.length() - 4;
            System.out.println(sbFilepath.insert(insertIdx, sProgType).toString());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sbFilepath.insert(insertIdx, sProgType).toString());
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle
        }

        mScreenshot = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("onSurfaceCreated", "start");
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // Use culling to remove back faces.
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Enable depth testing
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    String[] attr = new String[]{"Position", "Texcoords"};
    String vertexShader = getVertexShader();
    String fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.passthroughfs);
    final int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mNormalProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.embossfs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mEmbossProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.boxblurfs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mBlurProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.edgefs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mEdgeProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.grayscalefs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mGrayScaleProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.negfs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mNegProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.toonshadingfs);
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    mToonshadingProgram = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, attr);

    //  mProgramHandle = mToonshadingProgram;
/*  switch (mProgramID){


    case 1:
        mProgramHandle = mNormalProgram;
    case 2:
        mProgramHandle = mEmbossProgram;
    case 3:
        mProgramHandle =  mBlurProgram;
    case 4:
        mProgramHandle = mEdgeProgram;
    case 5:
        mProgramHandle = mGrayScaleProgram;
    case 6:
        mProgramHandle = mNegProgram;
    default:
        mProgramHandle = mNormalProgram;

    }*/

    // Load the texture
    setEffect(mProgramID);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    mTextureDataHandle = TextureHelper.loadTexture(mActivityContext, mFilepath);
    Log.d("onSurfaceCreated", "done");

}

public MyGLRenderer(final Context activityContext, String file) {
    mActivityContext = activityContext;
    mFilepath = file;

    System.out.println("constructor");
    Log.d("MyGLRenderer constructor", "start construct");

    mVerticesPositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * mBytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mVerticesPositions.put(vertices).position(0);
    mTexcoordPositions = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texcoords.length * mBytesPerFloat)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    mTexcoordPositions.put(texcoords).position(0);
    Log.d("MyGLRenderer constructor", "done construct");
    mScreenshot = false;

}

protected String getVertexShader() {
    return RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mActivityContext, R.raw.passthroughvs);
}

protected String getFragmentShader(final int resourceId) {
    return RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mActivityContext, resourceId);
}

private void Draw() {
    setEffect(mProgramID);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    mVerticesPositions.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mVerticesPositions);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    mTexcoordPositions.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTexcoordHandle, mTexcoordDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mTexcoordPositions);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexcoordHandle);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}


public void setEffect(int programID) {
    switch (programID) {


        case 1:
            mProgramHandle = mNormalProgram;
            break;
        case 2:
            mProgramHandle = mEmbossProgram;
            break;
        case 3:
            mProgramHandle = mBlurProgram;
            break;
        case 4:
            mProgramHandle = mEdgeProgram;
            break;
        case 5:
            mProgramHandle = mGrayScaleProgram;
            break;
        case 6:
            mProgramHandle = mNegProgram;
            break;
        case 7:
            mProgramHandle = mToonshadingProgram;
            break;
        default:
            mProgramHandle = mToonshadingProgram;
            break;
    }
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

}

public void setPorgID(int id) {
    mProgramID = id;

}

public String getProgramType() {
    switch (mProgramID) {
        case 1:
            return "normal";
        case 2:
            return "emobss";
        case 3:
            return "blur";
        case 4:
            return "edge";
        case 5:
            return "grayscale";
        case 6:
            return "negative";
        case 7:
            return "toonshading";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

public void saveImage() {

    mScreenshot = true;
}
```

}

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: may be you text on device dosn't support OpenGL

Comment: may be try use vec4 instead of vec2 ? It's a long shot

Comment: What we would really need to see is your shader code. Note that there is no default precision for floats in OpenGL ES fragment shaders. Based on the error message, you may be missing to specify this default. There should be something like "precision mediump float" close to the start of your fragment shader.